# Unexpected exception during symbol building (rebuildModuleMaps)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

I got a NullPointerException Error while building gradle in android studio, it was fine before, so the error kinda surprise the full error is

```
NullPointerException: Unexpected exception during symbol building (rebuildModuleMaps)
```

followed by another NullPointerException

```
Executing tasks: [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies]

NullPointerException: null
```

So what went missing exactly ?

Just to make things little bit clearer here is my list of disabled plugin

[image]

Comment: Have you tried enabling NDK support from Settings>Plugins?

Comment: @IshitaSinha i have actually, thats why i am a bit confused by this error.

Comment: enable the NDK workspacemanager support?

Comment: oh wow  @IshitaSinha the error's gone now, thankyou. Do you have any idea by the way as why the error's happened in the first place?

Comment: No, I'm not sure what causes this, but I've seen that enabling these two resolves the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that this error is due to Android NDK support being disabled. Re-enabling NDK support fixed this issue for me.

To re-enable Android NDK support, go to **Settings > Plugins** and enable the **Android NDK Support** and **NDK WorkspaceManager Support** plugins.